# Adding Chart to RDLC Report

Tags: c#, reporting, rdlc, reportviewer, report-designer

I have the following Report created with Microsoft Rdlc Report Designer for Visual Studio:
[image]
which Iam rendering to PDF. This works fine.

If I add an empty chart to the report like this:
[image]

Iam instantly getting the following Exceptions, when trying to render the report to pdf:

```
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalProcessingException  An error occurred during local report processing
InnerException: The definition of the report '' is invalid.
InnerException: The report definition is not valid.  Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.
```

Since the chart is empty and it is not connected to any `DataSet` I can't see why this is not working.

Can chart's only be filled with data from aa SQL-Server? Is this why the exceptions are thrown?

Can chart's be filled with data from dataSets? If so, why is the exception thrown?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I kinda figured out what went wrong.
I think some of my nuget packages I was working with, mainly reporting packages had wrong versions.

I sadly can't say which version's I had or which one are correct, but it might help anyone to play arround with the versions.